# using my Windows 7 home premium laptop as a wireless access point

Tags: windows-7, wireless-access-point, ad-hoc-network, nexus-7

I want to share my wired Internet connection in my laptop with tmy android phone via wireless. I have been following [the tutorial GIVEN HERE](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot), but it's not working for me. As shown on this image,
[image]
Isn't MyiPodTouchNetwork supposed to be the name of the WiFi connection that is seen by my ohone? I mean, when the phone looks for available wifi connections, shouldn't it see a connection with this name on it's list? My phone isn't showing this connection on it's list. What could have gone wrong? I have made sure that Internet sharing is enabled as shown in this picture:
[image]

--- EDIT ---
It seems that using this feature in Windows 7 Home Premium has some issues. However, I was able to find [THIS POST that says it should be possible to enable this feature](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/254729-turn-windows-7-laptop-into-wireless-repeater-one-wireless-adapter.html) in Windows 7 Home Premium. I managed to get a new adapter called Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter created.. After I enable it in Windows and issue the command given in step 3 of the above mentioned forum post, it seems to start up and my wifi is detected by my android device, and seems to connect as well. However, the Internet is not working on the android device. As can be seen on this menu,

[image]

the windows menu shows that the miniport does not have Internet connection either. What does this mean? The small wifi symbol on the android device is supposed to show blue colour if internet is available I think. The wifi symbol is there, the available wifi connections menu shows that the signal strength is excellent, but it is greyed out and when I try to open a webpage in my android chrome browser it doesn't open. I would post a screenshot of the android screen too, but I am having problems downloading the adb drivers and my laptop isn't detecting it. If anyone has some ideas about the drivers please let me know about them as well. So far I have been to this website:
[http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus+7&p=20&s=16](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus%207&p=20&s=16)
There is a drop down menu called OS but it is greyed out for some reason. I had done it before in another computer window XP, but that drop down menu isn't showing any options this time and I have no idea why. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't tried that one, but that is using ad-hoc (peer to peer) connectivity. I did try this one to turn your laptop into an Access Point http://www.techradar.com/au/news/computing/pc/how-to-turn-your-windows-7-laptop-into-a-wireless-hotspot-657138

Comment: I managed to get it working, the android device detects the wifi and says is connected to it, the wifi strength is excellent, but there si no internet on the device. Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Look at all the hardware you have. iPod touch is not a WIFI router and depending on your Android device. It may have inbuilt Wi-Fi router ability's to allow other device to use it as a mobile Wi-Fi router, you should be able to see if you can allow other devices to connect to the Android device.

Now here's the hard part, first you need to remove the Androids Wi-Fi setting so it won't use you Sim card to get online though the 3g or 4g network, this will make the Android device work like a standard WI-FI router.

Now using you PC you need to open the network connection manger select your Wired LAN connection and bridge it to the Android WI-FI. This will make the Android device work as WI-FI router and broadcast your computers Wired connection, and the settings in the Android device must be selected to use WI-FI to connect to the internet.

What will happen is your computer is connected to the internet via the LAN and modem and also be connected to the Android WI-FI, but with the connection being Bridged the PC will share the connection with all devices that connect to the WI-FI. This is the only way of doing what you asked or go online and look for a WI-FI adapter. That will convert a USB modem to WI-FI, they have a LAN input as well. There about $20 they usually used for DODO WI-FI internet they supply a USB 3G modem with the Adapter to make it Wireless, then all you would have to do is remove the LAN cable for your computer and plug into that good luck

Comment: Please add punctuation and a few line breaks to make your post readable. With all due respect, this is an eyesore.